# Difference between count(*) and count(true) in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

what is the difference between the `select count(*)` and `select count(true)`?
so is there any different between the `count(*)` and `count(true)` which one should I use?
can you give me situation example for each one that is better option to choose?

Comment: `count(*)` should be (slightly) faster: https://blog.jooq.org/whats-faster-count-or-count1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of both is the same, but `count(*)` is slightly faster than `count(true)`. That is because in the first case, the aggregate function has no arguments (that's what the `*` means in SQL), whereas in the second case the argument `true` is checked for NULLness, since `count` skips rows where the argument is NULL.

Comment: I think that's the answer that I wanted thanks

Answer (score 1):

The same result, it will give you total number of rows in a table

Comment: the result would be the same but in some queries `count(true)` is faster than the `count(*)` so we should know when we have to use `count(*)` and when `count(true)`. So right know I tested queries by explain analyze and I saw the time would be different .

Comment: @YasamanForouzesh  you can learn more on it  using this link https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-count-distinct/